# Java Selenium DevTools V105

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using selenium 4 devtools in my tests. Recently, my local browser got updated to v105. However, doesn't seem like mvn repository has artifacts to support it. The latest version is available v104 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-devtools-v104. With that, is there any work around I can utilize until v105 becomes available

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Right now I am using [Selenium 4.8.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/4.8.1) which is latest as of 22/03/2023 and my Google Chrome Version is V111 which is also latest. However, [Selenium 4.8.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/4.8.1) only Supports V85, V108, V109 and V110. Google Chrome version will be updated first and then selenium will add DevTool support for latest version, so most likely you will see this [WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 111, so returning the closest version found: 110](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlkbj.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

Download 4.5.0 Selenium Verison. Need not to add selenium devtools dependency seperately. It has CDP support for v104, v105, and v106 also.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/CHANGELOG

Comment: yes, you are right. figured this out. Thank you for posting the answer